# Limit the number of transaction per seconds on HTTP persistent connection Using Netty (http client)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, netty

Is there any mechanism/api by which I can control TPS hits from http client?

From HTTP client, I need to control numbers of hits to rest services (my HTTP client will hit to server in controlled manner).

Comment: A few more details would be helpful:
1. How is your client invoked?  Is it a simple console application or is it running as a web service itself?
2. If it is a service, does it have a DB?

If it is simply an app in a while(true) app, use a Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

you can close it immediately by adding a Netty's IpFilterHandler to server pipeline as the first handler. It will also stop propagating the upstream channel state events for filtered connection too.

```
 @ChannelHandler.Sharable
 public class FilterIPHandler extends IpFilteringHandlerImpl {
 private final Set<InetSocketAddress> deniedIP;

public filter(Set<InetSocketAddress> deniedIP) {
     this.deniedIP = deniedIP;
 }

 @Override
 protected boolean isAnAccpetedIP(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelEvent e,  InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress) throws Exception {
       return !deniedIP.contains(inetSocketAddress);
 }
 }
```